# Problems to ignore SSL errors on .net core 1.1 on windows

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate

I have a problem to ignore SSL certificate validation. Mi code is the next.

```
using (var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler())
{
  httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => { return true; };
  using (var client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
  {
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);  
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(
"api/token", vm);
    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    return Ok(result);
  }
}
```

I think that everything is fine, but when calling my Web Api for Https, this error appears:
"An error while sending the request. Te operation timed out".

Any idea?
thanks in advance.

Comment: SSL validation, or lack thereof, should not cause timeouts.  This sounds like a different problem.

Comment: Check that your URL is correct that you are creating the BaseAddress with.

Comment: The URL is correct, I have checked. Something else you can check? thanks