# Error calling Web Api (Asp net core 1.1). The operation timed out

Tags: c#, https, asp.net-core-webapi, asynchttpclient

I have a problem when I call the Web Api, i get the following error:

> An error occurred while sending the request..The operation timed out

Any idea? I do not know where to follow.
Thanks in advance.

```
using (var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler())
{
  httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => { return true; };
  using (var client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
  {
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);  
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(
"api/token", vm);
    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    return Ok(result);
  }
}
```

Comment: are you working with oauth 2.0 authentication ?

Comment: No, i am working with JWT

Comment: Isn't this the same question you asked on Friday?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49175786/problems-to-ignore-ssl-errors-on-net-core-1-1-on-windows
What investigation have you done?
What happens if you remove the httpclienthandler callback? Do you get the same error? Can you use postman to talk to the API you are using? Who owns the API you are trying to use?

Comment: yes, it is the same question, but i figured out that the problem is not the certificate. On the same server I have the client and the web api, from there, the client calls the web api without problems. The problem comes when you try to access the web API from an external client, through a public IP, in this case the Postman, can not access the Web API. The error produced is: "An error occurred while sending the request..The operation timed out". I do not know how to continue